# (Quickblox) Receiving Video Calls from anywhere in the App

Tags: iphone, ios, quickblox

This applies to iOS programming specifically using QuickBlox's API for video calls.

Obviously you don't want users to receive video calls in just one view controller in the app, so you need to make users be able to receive calls anywhere in the app.

Before I spend hours figuring out how to do this, I'm wondering how to tackle this issue.

I'm guessing that it has something to do with the `- (void) chatDidReceiveCallRequestFromUser` function in the AppDelegate, and having an alert view pop up over any view in the apps.

**How do you make QuickBlox video calls receivable while being in any view of the app?**

Answer (score 1):

In my application I created singleton class which conform QBChatDelegate protocol. In this class I implemented all needed methods and created @property with my viewController in which I realized all video chat code. So when call request coming I make all needed operation and call viewController's QBChatDelegate methods and if I need - present view controller by using TabBarController or in any other way.

Comment: Alexey can you share your example code thanks because i am working on app where chat and video on same view but i face some problem like chat or video one thing is working and one is not ..

Comment: Hello Alexey How you implemented all needed methods in class and in which class so i get the video call anywhere in my apps